# How to go to the main window from popup in C# using "IWebDriver"?

Tags: c#, .net

**Code for help**

```
      String parentWindowHandle = browser.getWindowHandle(); // save the current window handle.
      WebDriver popup = null;
      Iterator<String> windowIterator = browser.getWindowHandles();
      while(windowIterator.hasNext()) { 
      String windowHandle = windowIterator.next(); 
      popup = browser.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
        if (popup.getTitle().equals("Google") {
          break;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i correctly understood.

```
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
  driver.switchTo().window(handle);
}
```

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/NextSteps